# What is the Apple Mikey HID Driver for?

Tags: mac, macbook

Cheers,

does anyone know what component in Macbook identifies itself as "Apple Mikey HID Driver"? Joystick and Gamepad Tester detected my gamepad, the keyboard (with each key as a separate axis/button/whatever) and this mysterious device (with single axis/button identified as 'Page: 0x6, Usage: 0x22' which doesn't update).

This is in white Unibody Macbook '09.

Remark: While Googling for the component, I stumbled upon [this mailing list post](http://www.mail-archive.com/realbasic-nug@lists.realsoftware.com/msg07514.html) mentioning Apple IR?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like AppleMikeyDriver.kext handles events from buttons on a headset plugged in to the headphone port.

I'm not sure if this is all it does, but I can get ControllerMate to detect a "System Menu Select" key from this driver when I push the button on an old iPhone microphone/headset.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely Driver for the built in Microphone.

I did Google for AppleMikeyDriver or AppleMikeyDriver.kext (these are the OS X versions) and while there was no clear answer, there were a few (like parts from the syslog) which indicated a relationship to sound which makes sense with the given name too.

Comment: That makes little sense; microphone is not a human input device (HID); what is it doing representing itself as such?

Comment: It's a subcomponent of The HDA kext, and given the number of audio controls which are present on your keyboard, it's not surprising that there might be an HID driver for them.

Comment: @IvanVučica How is the microphone not a "human input device", exactly?    It's a device, to be sure.  It takes input, there's no doubt about that (I assume).  And any meaningful input comes from a human or reasonable facsimile, does it not?

Comment: @SamuelEdwinWard Why are you coloring your teeth blue? How much does fare cost when riding the USB serially into farthest reaches of the known universe? Your interpretation makes sense if you look not at what "HID" represents, but at individual words. USB and Bluetooth HID devices are a very specific class of devices which don't include audio input devices, covered by a different USB class. If you are looking for a Magic Carpet, that, however, is a part of the HID specs.